SOAP requests in spring boot 3.1.9
I am trying to make a soap call using java files generated from WSDL in spring boot 3.1.9. while making the soap call facing the following issue

com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap          : SAAJ0539: Unable to get header stream in saveChanges
com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap          : SAAJ0540: Error during saving a multipart message
Could not write message to OutputStream: Error during saving a multipart message

Tried removing xercersImpl depenedency.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

On further analysis I found out that when trying to manuplate the header for a SOAP request in the doWithMessage() public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) is throwing the above discussed exception.
